# How to shift two CDF's to maximize the number of crossings

Tags: probability, numerical-methods

So suppose I have two continuous, monotone increasing function $F$ and $G$ defined on an interval $I_F=\{x:0<F(x)<1\}=(l_F,u_F)$ and $I_G=\{x:0<G(x)<1\}=(l_G,u_G)$ which can be computed but don't have an analytical form.$(l_G,u_G)$ and $(l_F,u_F)$, however, are known.

Consider the function:

$$M=\max_{a\in I_A}S(F,G,a)$$

--where $S(F,G,a)$ counts the number of times $F(x)$ and $G(x+a)$ cross--

Given $F$ and $G$ and $I_A$, I would like to know if $M>1$. The issue is that $F(x)$ and $G(x+a)$  are very expensive to evaluate. What I mean is computing $F$ and $G$ for a grid of values of $x$ on $I_F$ and $I_G$ is do-able but trying all values of $G(x+a)$ for all shifts $a\in I_A$ (the naive solution) is definitely not.

What is the smart way to approach this problem?

P.S.: @Modo: if you think this is not the correct venue to ask this type of question, please let me know and I will try to find a better place. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a chance to invert $F$ or $G$, i.e. compute $F^{-1}(y)$ or $G^{-1}(y)$ rather cheaply?

Comment: As a matter of fact it can be done! Evaluating F^{-1}, G^{-1} costs about the same as evaluating F and G

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A crossing 
$$
F(x) = G(x + a)
$$
can be written as
$$
G^{-1}(F(x)) = x + a
$$
or
$$
a = G^{-1}(F(x)) - x.
$$
So counting the number of times $y = F(x)$ and $y = G(x+a)$ cross is equivalent to counting the number of times $y = a$ and $y = G^{-1}(F(x)) - x$ cross.

The function $S(a)$ changes only when $y = a$ passes through some extremum of $y = G^{-1}(F(x)) - x$, that is
$$
F'(x) = G'(G^{-1}(F(x)))
$$
or using $z = F(x)$
$$
F'(F^{-1}(z)) = G'(G^{-1}(z)) \tag{*}
$$
If there's at least one solution to the $(*)$ and that is an extremum (not an inflection point) then $S$ changes by 2 when $y = a$ passes through the extremum.

Consider an example
$$
F(x) = \tanh x\\
G(x) = \frac{2\arctan \pi x}{\pi}
$$
Inspecting their graphs shows three intersection points ($S = 3$ for $a = 0$).

The equation $(*)$ becomes
$$
1 - z^2 = 1 + \cos \pi z
$$
with roots
$$
z = \pm 1,\quad z \approx \pm 0.629847
$$
The $z = \pm 1$ roots are spurious, but the $z = \pm 0.629847$ are true ones and those correspond to $x = F^{-1}(z) \approx \pm 0.741163$.

Finally, evaluating $G^{-1}(F(x)) - x$ there gives the desired critical values for $a$:
$$
a \approx \pm 0.256836
$$
Here's a picture of $G(x)$ vs $F(x - 0.256836)$
[image]

Comment: Fantastic answer! I will add a bounty as soon as it is possible.

Comment: (apparently I have to un-accept the answer so I can add a bounty in a couple of hours).

Comment: @user1963 I'm glad if my answer comes useful, but an accept would be quite enough. You might want to save your reputation to attract people to problems that are really important to you.

Comment: It an objectively great answer. One can bestow a bounty to attract attention to a great answer;)